# Download file, issue with slashes

Tags: href

I use this to download a PDF:

```
echo '<a href= "' .$lineDetails[0]. '"> file </a>'
```

When I click `file`, the file doesn't download, because the anchor href is 
 `http://www.pas.com/\\admin\mypdffile.pdf`

How can I format the link to be `http://www.pas.com//admin/mypdffile.pdf` forward slash.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because `$lineDetails[0]` provides  windows style path to a file. You must somehow replace your backslashes in the path by normal slashes.

**EDIT - Hope you do not mind Hast**

Use [str-replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to do this

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_replace` to replace them. The code will be:

```
echo '<a href= "' . str_replace('\\', '/', $lineDetails[0]) . '"> file </a>';
```